# cmd : getting results and if statement

Tags: dos

Hi I am having problems with one of my first CMD scripts, any suggestions on how to go about this loop with grabbing the results outputted the command window with the if statements?

```
@echo off

:BEGIN

T:
cd js
cd ddf
cd invent


for %%s in ("invstk" "labmas") do ( 

Call Isutl -r %%s 


if result contains "%ISUTL=20: Cannot open index file" goto SendEmail else if the result = "Indexing Complete" continue to next file in 

list, if result not contains "%ISUTL=20: Cannot open index file" or "Indexing Complete" then call Isutl -r on that file again


)


:SendEmail


:DONESCAN
Exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this does what you need:

```
@echo off

:BEGIN

cd /d "t:\js\ddf\invent"
for %%s in ("invstk" "labmas") do call :routine "%%s"
del file.log 2>nul
pause
goto :EOF

:routine
Call Isutl -r "%~1" >file.log 2>&1
find /i "ISUTL=20: Cannot open index file" <file.log >nul && goto SendEmail
find /i "Indexing Complete" <file.log >nul && goto :EOF
goto :routine

:SendEmail
rem send email
goto :EOF
```